# Proof that any polynomial with a positive leading coefficient is eventually positive?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

The exact theorem I've been asked to prove is the following:

Suppose $f(x)=a_n x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ...+a_0$ is a polynomial of degree $n>0$ and suppose $a_n>0$. Then there is an integer $k$ such that if $x>k$, then $f(x)>0$.

(This is working up to the proof that any polynomial of degree $n>0$ is a composite number for infinitely many integers $x$.)

I have a suspicion that the proof I'm stuck on is extremely simple but I can't even think of where to begin.

Any help/hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: Factor out $x^n$.

Comment: Thanks! That was the hint I needed to get me on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(x)=x^n\left(a_n+a_{n-1}\frac1x+a_{n-2}\frac1{x^2}+\ldots+a_1\frac1{x^{n-1}}+a_0\frac1{x^n}\right)$$
Now for large $x$ the quantity $a_{n-1}\frac1x+a_{n-2}\frac1{x^2}+\ldots+a_1\frac1{x^{n-1}}+a_0\frac1{x^n}$ is smaller in absolute value than $a_n$ (is close to $0$), therefore $a_n+a_{n-1}\frac1x+a_{n-2}\frac1{x^2}+\ldots+a_1\frac1{x^{n-1}}+a_0\frac1{x^n}$ is positive. To prove that, use that $$a_n>0\text{ and }\lim_{x\to\infty}a_n+a_{n-1}\frac1x+a_{n-2}\frac1{x^2}+\ldots+a_1\frac1{x^{n-1}}+a_0\frac1{x^n} =a_n$$ and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/418337/39722) answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $|a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \ldots + a_0| \le \ldots x^{n-1}$ for $x > 1$.